# reorganize Git after massive manual changes

Tags: git, github

I have a remote git repo where I worked with a team, a member -not familiar with git - added a lot of manual changes and new files. long story short, a big mess. How can I rearrange git to track all files again from zero. 
Should I create and init a new .git file again or there is a command that scans new files and new changes ?
I mean by manual changes, changes directly made on the file, not via pushed commits. so untracked changes.
I don't care about the history, I just need all my files tracked from now on.

Comment: First you approach the unfamiliar member and just cut his hands off. Second, if you don't want to keep track of the mess you create a new repo or you overwrite the history and `git reset --hard` the repo.

Comment: First you approach the unfamiliar member, explain the concept of version control in general and git in particular, and teach him how to do stuff properly. Would have been smart to do this *before* he had the chance to break stuff...

Comment: @kowsky The member was here before I come. Not my fault :)

Comment: First you must know whether you want keep or no the Git history. better to create a new git file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start a new branch without history, just make an orphan checkout like `git checkout --orphan new-master`. Then arrange the files how you like them and create a commit. This commit will have no history, but be a root commit itself. You can then also point the `master` branch to this new commit and do a force-push.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** - As I noted, the question doesn't seem clear; and discussion in the comments indicates that the problem is different than I understood it.  so we'll try this again, but just in case I'll leave the original answer below:

So, it sounds like your team member wrote directly to a deployed environment?  Probably shouldn't be possible, but ok... are you asking how to revert his changes, or how to incorporate them into the git history?

If the deployed environment is itself a git repo, then it just has a bunch of local uncommitted changes.  `git status` should show what they are and how to deal with them (whether to revert or keep).

If the deployed environment is *not* a git repo, you could copy its contents over the worktree of a repo and commit or revert from there.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Honestly the question isn't 100% clear, but I *think* I understand what you want to do.  So you have

```
A --- B --- C --- X <--(master)
```

where `X` is a "bad" commit.  You ask about tracking everything "from zero"; by definition that's a new repo, but since you're asking I have to assume you're looking for something better; presumably because the history before `X` is valuable.

You have a couple options.  Note that any fix is easiest if `X` is the HEAD, and that's how I'll show them.  If not, follow up in comments and we can sort out how to adapt whichever technique you prefer.

You can revert the commit (create a new commit that undoes everything it did).

```
git revert HEAD
```

In a shared repository this is the safest solution, but it does keep `X` in the final history.

```
A --- B --- C --- X --- ~X <-- (master)
```

The tree at `~X` will match the tree at `C`.

If you really must remove `X` from the history, you can do that, but everyone who accesses the repository will have to "recover" from the fact that a ref will have moved in an unexpected way.

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git push -f
```

Now anyone who has `X` locally will have to get back in sync; see the section "RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE" in the git docs here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: There are a lot of manual changes and files added without git, will this work with my case ?

Comment: Perhaps we should clarify what you mean "manual changes".  And in particular, what is a file "added without git"?  If it's in the repo, it was added with git; if not, where are you seeing it?

Comment: I mean by manual changes, changes directly made on the file, not via pushed commits. so untracked changes

Comment: Again, you would not see such changes in the repo.  Where are you seeing them?